# req.params returns undefined (it actually returns :itemId as a string so it's kind of undefined) instead of the id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

it's been a few days that I do not know what is wrong with my code and couldn't find any solution for this.

I tried also to get the id with query (moving the controllers on the shop routes and, of course, changing the : with the ?), and, also with req.body trying to get the input with the id but it didn't work.

I also tried POST and PATCH instead of GET and it didn't work

here is my code:

auth.js (controller)

```
exports.addToCart = async (req, res, next) => {

try {

    // getting the user id from the session so that we can find this user
    const userId = req.session.user._id.toString();

    // finding the user
    const user = await User.findById(userId);

    const itemId = req.params.itemId;

    console.log(itemId) // returns exactly :itemId as a string (so it does not return the actual item id)
    
    const item = await Item.findById(itemId);
    console.log(item); // returns an error because of course the id is wrong
    
} catch (err) {

    console.log(err);

    if(!err.statusCode) {

        err.statusCode = 500;

    }

}
};
```

auth.js (route)

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:itemId', authController.addToCart);
```

and then on the frontend I first pass as props the item id to the AddToCart component like this:

Shop Component where I load all the items from the database:

```
                    <ItemStyle key={item._id}>

                    <h1>title</h1>
                    <p>{item.title}</p>

                    <img alt={item.title} src={item.image}></img>

                    <h1>description</h1>
                    <p>{item.description}</p>

                    <h1>price</h1>
                    <p>{item.price}</p>

                    <AddToCart itemId={item._id} />
                
                </ItemStyle>
```

AddToCart component:

```
class AddToCart extends Component {

addToCart = async () => {

    await fetch(`http://localhost:8090/auth/add-to-cart/:itemId`, {

        method: 'GET',

        headers: {

            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        },

        credentials: 'include',

    })

    .then(() => { 

        /* staying on the same page */
        return window.location.replace('/shop');

    })

    .catch(err => console.log(err));

}

render() {

    return(

        <form encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

            <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value={this.props.itemId} />

            <button onClick={this.addToCart}>Add To Cart</button>

        </form>

    )

}

}
```

if I remove the type="hidden" from the input I can actually see that the right id is assigned to that item. Anyone has a solution for this? If for some reasons I am going against stackoverflow policies please let me know and I will update the question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You said `console.log(itemId)` returns the `itemId` ? Is it returning the `itemId` or `undefined`? And can you try to log `req.params` too please?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. it actually returns :itemId as a string (so not the actual id), sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you should do -

1. Remove await in side addToCart function, it should not be used with "then".
2. Inside addToCart function, make sure you are getting itemId value.
3. Change API end point -

   `http://localhost:8090/auth/add-to-cart/${itemId}`

Comment: Hi, you saved me! I did get the itemId inside the function with this line this.props.itemId and changed the API point as you suggested and now it is working just fine! Thank you so much!! If you tell me how, I will accept your answer (I always see this kind of comment in questions but to be honest I have no idea on what accepting an answer does).

Comment: In Shop Component, you are passing *itemId* argument to AddToCart component which comes via props. Props are basically arguments passed into react components. Props are used to pass data from one component to another. In addToCart function, there is no local variable "itemId" as value is in props. That's why to access the value from props, we use *this.props.itemId*

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I meant to say that I did find the itemId into the function AFTER I read your comment. If it wasn't for you I wouldn't have solved it. Thank you again!

Comment: Also, I did accept your answer since you were 1st and it is the one with most content

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem

You shouldn't use `.then()` and await together. I suggest you to use `await` only. Like this:

```
var response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8090/auth/add-to-cart/${itemId}`, {

    method: 'GET',

    headers: {

        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    },

    credentials: 'include',

});
```

Also, if you notice, I used `${itemId}` above. If you want to set a variable in a string. You have to use it like that.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's actually how I solved the issue (I also had to find the id inside of the addToCart function).

Comment: @msorr95 Ah great to hear it. Feel free to accept my answer ;)